# Regular Expression for numbers with chance of having the decimal

Tags: java, regex

Guys I just started learning Regular Expression in java. I am trying to construct a regular expression for a number. It is ok for integers if I use "\d+".

But if there is any decimal number, it is obvious that the above RE won't work.
So I constructed a RE that is "\d+\.\d+" . It is ok for decimal numbers but
NOT FOR INTEGERS.

So I want to make a RE for BOTH INTEGERS and DECIMALS. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Try: `\b\d+(\.\d+)?\b`

Comment: You can find here a solution [regex for integer and double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156320/extract-a-double-or-integer-from-a-string-using-regular-expression-in-java)

Comment: but i may get upto 10 places of decimal. @anubhava, that will do. :)

Comment: Though remember it won't match e.g. `.25`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the part after the decimal point optional.

```
"\d+(?:\.\d+)?"
```

The leading `?:` after the initial parenthesis is just to avoid creating a matching group.

Comment: Yes that is absolutely correct.... Thanx a lot.
But I dont know why someone downvoted my question??? :(

Comment: This is not entrely correct as it will also match 3_4, 3:5 and 4a3 because . is a wildcard in regex. You need to escape it.

Comment: Thanks. Just a typo, by bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this regex:

```
/^\d*\.?\d*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for [java.lang.Double#valueOf(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) gives a detailed but well-documented regular expression for how it parses numbers. You may find it instructive to read that and work out which parts are relevant to your problem.